# Handle TargetDisconnectedException with Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

I have a problem with HazelcastClient (Java) when the cluster goes down.
The version of Hazelcast is the last one 3.8.1 for both client and cluster

Periodically I have the following code which is executed

```
getMap().executeOnEntries(new MyProcessor<>(), Predicates.equal("field", var));
```

The problem is that when the cluster goes down, The error thrown by hazelcast only logs warning but don't throw an exception:

```
2017-04-28 18:32:19,905 [WARN] from com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager in hz.client_0.internal-1 - hz.client_0 [aa-api] [3.8.1] Heartbeat failed to connection : ClientConnection{alive=true, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/xxx.xxx.4.125:49688 remote=/xxx.xxx.8.118:5701]}, remoteEndpoint=[xxx.xxx.8.118]:5701, lastReadTime=2017-04-28 18:31:15.445, lastWriteTime=2017-04-28 18:32:14.905, closedTime=never, lastHeartbeatRequested=2017-04-28 18:32:14.905, lastHeartbeatReceived=2017-04-28 18:31:14.905, connected server version=3.8.1}
2017-04-28 18:32:20,884 [WARN] from com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientPartitionService in hz.client_0.internal-3 - hz.client_0 [aa-api] [3.8.1] Error while fetching cluster partition table!
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetDisconnectedException: Heartbeat timed out to owner connection ClientConnection{alive=true, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/xxx.xxx.4.125:49688 remote=/xxx.xxx.8.118:5701]}, remoteEndpoint=[xxx.xxx.8.118]:5701, lastReadTime=2017-04-28 18:31:15.445, lastWriteTime=2017-04-28 18:32:14.905, closedTime=never, lastHeartbeatRequested=2017-04-28 18:32:14.905, lastHeartbeatReceived=2017-04-28 18:31:14.905, connected server version=3.8.1}
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolve(ClientInvocationFuture.java:73)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at com.hazelcast.util.executor.LoggingScheduledExecutor$LoggingDelegatingFuture.run(LoggingScheduledExecutor.java:128)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetDisconnectedException: Heartbeat timed out to owner connection ClientConnection{alive=true, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/xxx.xxx.4.125:49688 remote=/xxx.xxx.8.118:5701]}, remoteEndpoint=[xxx.xxx.8.118]:5701, lastReadTime=2017-04-28 18:31:15.445, lastWriteTime=2017-04-28 18:32:14.905, closedTime=never, lastHeartbeatRequested=2017-04-28 18:32:14.905, lastHeartbeatReceived=2017-04-28 18:31:14.905, connected server version=3.8.1}
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceSupport$CleanResourcesTask.notifyException(ClientInvocationServiceSupport.java:229)
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceSupport$CleanResourcesTask.run(ClientInvocationServiceSupport.java:214)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetDisconnectedException: Heartbeat timed out to owner connection ClientConnection{alive=true, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/xxx.xxx.4.125:49688 remote=/xxx.xxx.8.118:5701]}, remoteEndpoint=[xxx.xxx.8.118]:5701, lastReadTime=2017-04-28 18:31:15.445, lastWriteTime=2017-04-28 18:32:14.905, closedTime=never, lastHeartbeatRequested=2017-04-28 18:32:14.905, lastHeartbeatReceived=2017-04-28 18:31:14.905, connected server version=3.8.1}
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport.heartbeatStopped(ClusterListenerSupport.java:259)
at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$Heartbeat.fireHeartbeatStopped(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:503)
at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$Heartbeat.run(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:462)
... 10 common frames omitted
2017-04-28 18:32:22,904 [WARN] from com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection in hz.client_0.internal-1 - hz.client_0 [aa-api] [3.8.1] ClientConnection{alive=false, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/xxx.xxx.4.125:49688 remote=/xxx.xxx.8.118:5701]}, remoteEndpoint=[xxx.xxx.8.118]:5701, lastReadTime=2017-04-28 18:31:15.445, lastWriteTime=2017-04-28 18:32:14.905, closedTime=2017-04-28 18:32:19.905, lastHeartbeatRequested=2017-04-28 18:32:14.905, lastHeartbeatReceived=2017-04-28 18:31:14.905, connected server version=3.8.1} lost. Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetDisconnectedException[Heartbeat timed out to owner connection ClientConnection{alive=true, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/xxx.xxx.4.125:49688 remote=/xxx.xxx.8.118:5701]}, remoteEndpoint=[xxx.xxx.8.118]:5701, lastReadTime=2017-04-28 18:31:15.445, lastWriteTime=2017-04-28 18:32:14.905, closedTime=never, lastHeartbeatRequested=2017-04-28 18:32:14.905, lastHeartbeatReceived=2017-04-28 18:31:14.905, connected server version=3.8.1}]
```

How can I handle this exception so I can take actions?

Thanks,

EDIT: the problem occurs also when the node I was connected to is disconnected. The client doesn't connect to another node (AWS Discovery).

Comment: What is your Hazelcast version (both client / server)?

Comment: Thanks, any specific hazelcast(-client).xml configurations?

Comment: Actually, after three days of research, I found that it was a problem of configuration. Actually, there is a missing feature for the reconnection: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/9692. Also, the heartbeat was too high, so the client was not able to detect the dead node in time. By modifying the configuration and verifying before operation the health, I can now detect dead node

Comment: Glad it was solved :) You might want an answer yourself to explain others what was wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot. You can comment the question or update it if you can/want

Answer (score 3):

The problem was mainly about configuration. Some timeout and health checking interval were too high.

Bellow, the default properties for clients:

> hazelcast.client.heartbeat.interval = 10000ms
>
> hazelcast.client.heartbeat.timeout = 300000ms
>
> hazelcast.client.invocation.timeout.seconds = 120s

And here my new values

> hazelcast.client.heartbeat.interval = 2000
>
> hazelcast.client.heartbeat.timeout = 5000
>
> hazelcast.client.invocation.timeout.seconds = 10

Also, i reworked entirely the way I get maps, topics, and more generally, the hazelcast instance.

**At instanciation time**

I handle every exceptions (Mostly extending RuntimeException), and I notify each classes using it that the instance is now available.

```
try {
    hazelcastInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
    eventListeners.forEach(HazelcastEventListener::onConnect);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    Logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    return null;
}
```

**Before each requests which use the instance**

I call a code which verify the availability of the instance, and if an error occurs, I notify each classes using it that the instance is down.

```
public boolean isClientActive() {
    if (getInstance() == null) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        getMap("registration").isLocked("a");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        hazelcastInstance = null;
        eventListeners.forEach(HazelcastEventListener::onDisconnect);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Get notified when a member left**

```
// add a membership listener on the cluster
// to get notified when a member is removed
hazelcastInstance.getCluster().addMembershipListener(new MembershipListener() {
    @Override
    public void memberAdded(MembershipEvent membershipEvent) {}

    @Override
    public void memberRemoved(MembershipEvent membershipEvent) {
        if (membershipEvent.getMembers().isEmpty()) {
            restartInstance();
        }
    }
```

**Handling of my HazelcastEventListener**

Each class using hazelcast registers an eventListener

```
    hazelcastManager.addEventListener(new HazelcastEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnect() {
            map = hazelcastManager.getMap(mapName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnect() {
            map = null;
        }
    });
```

**Reconnecting hazelcast client**

Calling getInstance() will try to reconnect when the hazelcastInstance is null.

**Problems**

It avoid many errors, but there is some work left to do, to manage concurrency problems.
Actually, I consider this solution as a workaround since it's not very efficient, and mostly patches on a missing feature in Hazelcast.

That's why I will not "accept" this solution. If someone has a better solution, please let us know.